# Java : Difference between -Dweblogic and setting values in weblogic console

Tags: java, parameters, console, client, weblogic

I tried to google for this question, but did not get any promising answers. What is the difference between setting weblogic configuration paramter values on java client side by using -Dweblogic.XXX and setting the same parameter value in weblogic administration console.

e.g. If we consider CompleteMessageTimeout paramter, i can configure it on my java client side using

```
-Dweblogic.CompleteMessageTimeout=300
```

At the same time I can also configure it in weblogic admin console, in AdminServer -> Protocols -> General tab.

What is the difference between these two approaches? Is it like values set on the client side overrides the values set in admin server console?

Comment: my guess is like in console configuration is perment for all. if u add parameter in java client i.e is for only this time.

Answer (score 0):

When you use -Dweblogic.XXX option you can ovverride console configuration.

Comment: I also had the same understanding. But I found this line: "For applications that handle large amounts of data per request, increasing the value on both the client and server sides can boost performance." Refer [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/perform/WLSTuning.html#1152088) section: Tune the Chunk Parameters. This makes me little bit confusing.

Comment: Because some of -Dweblogic.XXX  parameters are client side, for example -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize - you can only set this parameter for client, so it's impossible to set it in console configuration.

Comment: You sure? I really doubt that. Weblogic console should allow to configure each and every parameter. e.g. Maximum message size can be configured in AdminServer -> Protocols -> General tab

Comment: Yes, you have right.
But setting parameters in console have scope only for server.
For clients you are able to set parameters only with command line arguments.